# I've to re-size div when accordion closes and opens

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery

I am having a div which is placed below the accordion. When the accordion closed the size of the div should increase, when the accordion opened the size of the div should decrease. Kindly help on this issue.... Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please post any code you have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can we see some code? It's difficult to say without that..

Maybe you could hook in to the accordion closing script and add something like this:

```
document.getElementById("YOUR-DIV").style.height = 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the accordion's `activate` event.  When creating the accordion specify the function to be executed when the activate event is trigger.  The activate event is executed when a panel is opened.

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({
   activate: function( event, ui ) {
     //Adjust div size.
   }
});
```